# YAML, timestamps, and SnakeYAML Engine

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm unsure how YAML "timestamps" are supposed to be represented. From the [YAML 1.2 specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), it would seem that YAML just assumes that if you have a value in string format that looks like an ISO 8601 date, then it is parsed as a date unless you say differently. Here are a couple of examples from the spec:

```yaml
date: 2002-12-14
not-date: !!str 2002-04-28
```

The [Timestamp Language-Independent Type for YAML™ Version 1.1](https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html) working draft (from 2005, currently 15 years ago!) seems to indicate that a special tag in the form `tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp` should be used. It also indicates a shorthand of `!!timestamp`.

In Java using [SnakeYAML Engine](http://SnakeYAML%20Engine) v2.0 (`org.snakeyaml:snakeyaml-engine:2.0`) I tried parsing the `2002-12-14` form, and got a string as the parsed value, not any sort of date object. I see that the SnakeYAML Engine repository has an [example](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml-engine/src/master/src/test/java/org/snakeyaml/engine/usecases/tags/TimestampTagTest.java) using the `!!timestamp` approach (e.g. `!!timestamp 2020-03-24T12:34:00.333`), but this is a recent change and I'm sure if this support has been released yet.

I tried both the form `fooBar: !!timestamp 2020-03-24` and also `fooBar: !!timestamp 2020-03-24T12:34:00.333`, but SnakeYAML Engine reported:

```
could not determine a constructor for the tag tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp
```

So what is the official way to represent a date (specifically a local date with YYYY-MM-DD) in YAML, and is the correct approach reflected in the latest YAML specification? Does SnakeYAML Engine support the official YAML date approach?

Answer (score 1):

> From the YAML 1.2 specification, it would seem that YAML just assumes that if you have a value in string format that looks like an ISO 8601 date, then it is parsed as a date unless you say differently.

No. The YAML spec gives three schemas (Failsafe, JSON and Core) that *should* be supported; none of them includes a timestamp type. However, a scalar looking like a timestamp *can* be parsed as such if a schema is used that supports it. The spec only tells you that if you want to ensure that a scalar is *not* loaded as timestamp, prefix it with `!!str`.

> So what is the official way to represent a date (specifically a local date with YYYY-MM-DD) in YAML.

The `!!timestamp` definition you linked is closest to what an *official way* would be. However, the tag repository containing it is not part of the spec and implementations are not required to support it. Furthermore, it is defined for outdated YAML 1.1.

This means that SnakeYAML isn't required to support timestamps at all. You can see in the example you give that timestamp support is not included; the example implements loading timestamps itself. You can modify that code to use with the normal public interface:

```java
class TimestampConstructor extends Constructor {
    public static final Pattern TIMESTAMP = Pattern
            .compile("^(?:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]?-[0-9][0-9]?(?:[Tt]|[ \t]+)[0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](?:\\.[0-9]*)?(?:[ \t]*(?:Z|[-+][0-9][0-9]?(?::[0-9][0-9])?))?)$");
    public static final Tag TAG = new Tag(Tag.PREFIX + "timestamp");


    public TimestampConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(TAG, new ConstructTimestamp());
    }

    private class ConstructTimestamp extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            String val = (String) constructScalar(node);
            return LocalDateTime.parse(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new TimestampConstructor());
yaml.addImplicitResolver(TimestampConstructor.TAG,
        TimestampConstructor.PATTERN, "0123456789");
```